# Chrome extension events and nested callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I've seen this problem a few diffferent times, and I think there's some scope rule I've misunderstood.

In my popup html I have a button:

```
<button id="submit">Click Me</button>
```

and further down on  that page I also declare `<script>`s with `src` files. One script contains:

```
document.getElementById("submit").onclick=function(){
    var response = function(tab){
        alert('success ' + tab.id);
    };
    chrome.tabs.create({url: determineURL()}, response);
};
```

If I open the popup and click the button, the new tab opens to `determineURL()`, but the alert never executes. However, if I inspect the popup, effectively keeping it open while the new tab opens and loads, the alert *does* execute.

Comment: I know it's also possible to inject a script to matching urls, but the user of the extension might want to view the page both with and without the script injected, so I have to inject it programatically to the new tab opened from the extension.

Comment: Quick guess: the action of opening the tab auto-closes the extension popup, and scripts in that popup page can no longer run (since the page isn't open anymore). Activating the popup in inspect-mode forces it to stay alive through the tab creation.

Comment: Yes, that is the observed behavior. Inspecting the popup circumvents the auto-close, but is an obviously unacceptable solution.

Comment: So your question is *how* to make the alert occur -- you'll get more direct answers if you edit your question to make that more explicit. At present, it seems like you might simply be looking for an explanation of seemingly anomalous behavior. In any case, there's likely no scope rule that you've misunderstood; the page is probably just closing before the callback runs.

Comment: I've found out that a background script will do what I want, but I was wondering if there's a reason that the callback isn't actually... called back. This isn't the first time I've seen this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The callback is not called because the popup page closes chronologically before the callback can fire. Consider these two assertions:

- Creating a new tab with `chrome.tabs.create` immediately closes any open extension popup
- The `chrome.tabs.create` callback only fires *after* the tab is created
- It is not possible for a page that is not loaded to run scripts.

The script running in your popup page therefore goes like this:

1. The script in the popup create a tab
2. Popup is forced to close, due to a new tab opening
3. The script in the popup causes an alert

Note that step 3 is **impossible** (according to my third assertion, above), as long as step 2 is true. Using inspection mode make the popup persistent and prevents step 2 from occurring.